# Call an output from a python script to a secondary github action job

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this github action

```
createVNET:
  uses: blah/gitops-tf-azure-vnet/.github/workflows/plan.yml@main
  with:
    ref: "main"
    tgtAddress: echo "${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.vnet}}"
    tgtSubnet: echo "${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.subnet}}"
    subnetName: echo "${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.name}}"
  secrets: inherit
  needs: output_stuff
```

the three variables tgtAddress/tgtSubnet/SubnetName originate from a python script that reserves the subnet.

```
  output_stuff:
    runs-on:
      labels: ephemeral
    outputs:
      subnet: ${{ steps.subnets.outputs.subnet }}
      name: ${{ steps.names.outputs.name }}
      vnet: ${{ steps.vnets.outputs.vnet }}
    steps:
    - name: Output Chosen Subnet
      id: subnets
      run: |
        echo "subnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.cidr}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Output Chosen Appname
      id: names
      run: |
        echo "name=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.appName}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Output Chosen vnet
      id: vnets
      run: |
        echo "vnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.vnet}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    needs: reserveSubnet
```

The problem: when I run this github action the python script works the output_stuff job also works exporting exactly what I expect it to. But when we get to the job entitled createVnet I look at the logs as the actions running and inside the input variables, I see blanks or "echo "". Not sure what I'm going wrong here I've searched the internet and gpt with no avail. Anyone have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: I can see a few issues: your `output_stuff` steps write to the environment file, but it should be `GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead; the parameters for the call to `plan.yml` almost certainly shouldn't include `echo`, but just the `${{...}}` expressions;, and lastly, we don't see the `reserveSubnet` job, so it's not clear if the `output_stuff` job gets the correct inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that GITHUB_ENV variable is only available in subsequent steps in the job.

You should instead be echoing into GITHUB_OUTPUT i.e.:

```
output_stuff:
    runs-on:
      labels: ephemeral
    outputs:
      subnet: ${{ steps.subnets.outputs.subnet }}
      name: ${{ steps.names.outputs.name }}
      vnet: ${{ steps.vnets.outputs.vnet }}
    steps:
    - name: Output Chosen Subnet
      id: subnets
      run: |
        echo "subnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.cidr}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Output Chosen Appname
      id: names
      run: |
        echo "name=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.appName}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Output Chosen vnet
      id: vnets
      run: |
        echo "vnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.vnet}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    needs: reserveSubnet
```

**Note this assumes that the reserveSubnet job does the same and correctly returns it's outputs.**